# Random Number Generator - Android - xxx has stopped working

Tags: java, android, random, numbers, generator

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int minValue;
int maxValue;
int rndNum;

TextView rndNumText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Number);
EditText MinVal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMin);
EditText MaxVal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMax);
Button btnRandom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Randomize);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnRandom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            minValue = Integer.parseInt(MinVal.getText().toString());
            maxValue = Integer.parseInt(MaxVal.getText().toString());
            Random r = new Random();
            rndNum = r.nextInt(maxValue - minValue + 1) + minValue;
            rndNumText.setText(Integer.toString(rndNum));
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

I get no errors so eclipse allows me to run the program but when it is about to execute, it gives me an error saying "Unfortunately, *PROGRAM NAME* has stopped."

What did I do wrong? I would really appreciate your insight.

Comment: Please post the logcat of the error.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a bit new to android. I figured out how to get logcat to work but which parts of it should I copy/paste? There is 100 lines+ when I try to execute code lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the initialization of these

```
TextView rndNumText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Number);
EditText MinVal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMin);
EditText MaxVal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMax);
Button btnRandom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Randomize);
```

inside your `onCreate` after `setContextView()`, otherwise the view hasn't been initialized and given an id.

Comment: I tried that and it gave me even more errors saying 
"Cannot refer to a non-final variable MinVal inside an inner class defined in a different method"
"Cannot refer to a non-final variable MaxVal inside an inner class defined in a different method"
"Cannot refer to a non-final variable rndNumText inside an inner class defined in a different method"

Comment: @user3124331 Leave the declarations outside the method so that they are instance variables. Simply initialize them inside.

Comment: WOW it works now!!! TY!
I never understand why these kind of things happen (Declaring outside and initializing inside instead of doing both things inside the subprogram)

Comment: @user It depends on the scope you want your variables to have. Go through [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/). Also, consider accepting the answer.